# To make form tag with submit doesn't open a new page/window

Tags: python, html, cherrypy

So, there is an ordinary example of `form` tag usage:

```
<form name="form_name" action="${url}" method="POST">`
    <input type="text" name="email_input" id="email_input" class="input">
    <input type="submit" name="send" class="send_ticket">
</form>
```

How can you see, I use Mako in action value and Python web framework CherryPy. 
So, this code works fine: I push the button, data is sent to a server then a new tab is opened. But I requares in no displaying a new tab in my browser. I want to stay on my current tab.

How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is resolved by using `redirectToRoute` function.

Answer (score 1):

Since you completely changed your question, I am updating my answer.

By default, **all form posts happen in the same browser window**.

What you are describing seems as a very irregular behavior to me. Are you displaying the form in a popup such as colorbox or a jquery dialog and not mentioning it? or an iframe?

If not, you can try adding `target="_self"` to your form markup, but note that it is being deprecated and will not be supported by all browsers.

```
<form name="form_name" action="${url}" method="POST" target="_self">`
    <input type="text" name="email_input" id="email_input" class="input">
    <input type="submit" name="send" class="send_ticket">
</form>
```

And lastly, you can try using Ajax to post the form data without forcing a new page load.

[Here is a nice Tuts+ tutorial about Ajax form post.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but `target = "_blank"` means: _The response is displayed in a new window or tab_. But I need to not displaying new tab or window.

Comment: So you need it in the same page??? that's the default...I'm confused as what you were asking then

Comment: I updated the post. So, there is an inverse task. A new tab is always displayed and I don't need it. I want to stay on my current tab (where is the button)

Comment: @Dmitriy_Cert I revised my answer.

Comment: It's my mistake, I didn't say that I use Python web framework Cherrypy and my problem is resolved by using `redirectToRoute` function. @Yani Thank you for your answer nevertheless.